# Populate 3 consecutive dropdown lists based on the selection of other dropdown lists html and javascript araray

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, webforms

So I'm new to JavaScript and I've found about 100 different tutorials about dynamically updating a 2nd drop down list based off the selection of the first drop down but I am struggling to find a way to add a third dynamically updated list.

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nato5565/B9HGZ/) I am trying to modify which lets you select 'phone' from the first drop down and then updates the second drop down with types of phones.  I would like to add the ability to dynamically update a third drop down with plans if a certain phone is added. It would be nice if I could use arrays to update each list, but it isn't a must. Here's what I've got so far:

Html:

```
<select id="cat">
    <option val="car">car</option>
    <option val="phone">phone</option>
</select>

<select id="item">

</select>

<select id="plan">

</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');
plans=new Array('Sprint', 'Verizon','T-Molbile');

populateSelect();

$(function() {
      debugger;  
      $('#cat').change(function(){
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect(){

    cat=$('#cat').val();
    $('#item').html('');


    if(cat=='car'){
        cars.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

    if(cat=='phone'){
        phones.forEach(function(t) {
            $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

} 

function populateSelect1(){
    item=$('#item').val();
    $('#plan').html('');


    if(item=='IPhone'){
        plans.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#plan').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Here's the link:http://jsfiddle.net/nato5565/B9HGZ/

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to call your populateSelect1 method on the item change.